# Mvvm & Architecture of MAUI/Xamarin application

Tags: .net, xamarin, mobile, maui

I have a feeling that I am making a logical mistake somewhere.
In MAUI I have:

- Page A with AViewModel binded
- Page B with BViewModel binded

The pages are generic that is, they are used in different parts of the program. They display something, or handle some external device after which they send a message to the message center.

Let's say I now have a main menu and on it 2 buttons.

- Button 1
- Button 2

Button 1 calls ExamplePage, which then calls PageA/PageB via Navigation Service. ExamplePage listens for messages from PageA or PageB. In this scenario, everything works as expected.

Now the problematic case.

Button 2 when clicked should show PageA or PageB so one of the generic pages. Since I don't want the main menu to listen for messages from PageA /PageB ( since there can be 100 buttons and each of them can call PageA/PageB and then handle it differently) I decided to add a class I call StandaloneViewModel.

StandaloneViewModel is a ViewModel ( so it can refer to services, or navigate
navigate through different pages), which implements the IStandaloneViewModel interface, which contains only the Task Process() method;

So now:
Button 2 resolves Button2StandaloneViewModel (DI), and calls the await Process() method on it;
Button2StandaloneViewModel listens for PageA/PageB events and handles them appropriately for Button 2.
The Process() method calls await NavigateToPageA(), for example.
Such a process makes a Button2StandaloneViewModel , which handles the process for button 2 in an appropriate way, between the Main Menu and PageA.

Problems with such a solution:

1. when Button2 is clicked, PageA opens, the Button2StandaloneViewModel starts listening for messages. If we go back to the main menu, and call Button2 again, a new instance of the class is opened, making the message from Page2 handled 2x.  Most likely, the GC has not yet had time to clean it up
   Another problem with such a solution is that sometimes the process is more complicated and PageA -> Page->PageXXX and sending a message from PageXXX has no reaction in Button2StandaloneViewModel because this class is no longer there.

2 So I came up with the idea that maybe I will solve Button2StandaloneViewModel as singledon. Of course, this solution generated another downside, because once resolved the Button2StandaloneViewModel class, sits in memory and listens, so when I add Button3StandaloneViewModel and it also handles PageA, then events will be called for Button2StandaloneViewModel and Button3StandaloneViewModel.

I thought to try to somehow implement IDisposable on the StandaloneViewModel, but the Task Process method is asynchronous by which dispose executes immediately. (I remind you that the Process() method will only contain a redirect to another page, which is also asynchronous);

In addition, Pages are deposited on the stack, so when I back out of PageA to MainMenu, the program doesn't even know about the existence of StandaloneViewModel, so I have no way to call Dispose on it manually.

Probably the solution lies somewhere in the middle of my considerations but maybe you are somehow able to direct me?

--Edit
Reproduce :

1 The case that works well was served under the "Navigate to ExamplePage" button. It calls ExamplePage, which handles messages from Page1. When the user wants to return to the main menu, ExamplePage is pulled from the stack by which the listening for messages is also cleared, and there is no problem with possibly unregistering the listening manually.

Problem case:

1. click Navigate To StandaloneViewModel
2. click on ClickMe
3. click in StartAgain
4. back out via the arrow on the top bar
5. click in Navigate To Standalone2ViewModel
6. click in ClickMe <-- This is the point at which StandaloneViewModel and Standalone2ViewModel are listening for an event from Page1.

All I want to accomplish is to make sure that after step 4 is done, StandaloneViewModel stops listening for messages from Page1. Ideally, it would be as if the life cycle of this class, ended at all.

Obviously, in the uploaded example, singledon is configured on StandaloneViewModel, and this is the reason why the class does not stop listening, however, when it does not, there are problems with subsequent instances of StandaloneViewModel

To repeat without singledon:

Go to DependencyInjectionInitializer and modify RegisterViewModels like this:

```
        private static void RegisterViewModels()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var standaloneViewModelType = typeof(IStandaloneViewModel);

        var viewModels = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("ViewModel") && !x.Name.Contains("Base") && x.IsClass );
        foreach (var type in viewModels)
        {
            DependencyInjectionManager.GetInstance().ContainerBuilder.RegisterType(type);

        }

    }
```

1. click on Navigate To StandaloneViewModel
2. click on ClickMe
3. click in StartAgain
4. back out via the arrow on the top bar
5. repeat the process from step one <- The message handler on StandaloneViewModel will be called 2x because the class has not yet been cleared from memory, or diposed.

Comment: Well, we had to reconstruct the code from your description to help you. That will take some time (maybe weeks). So please be patient or post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hey, is it ok if I post example on github? https://github.com/adrianszklarz/StackQuestions

Comment: After a short look at your project: Is there a special reason why you **not** use the already builtin DI Container? BTW: getting the instances for navigation and messaging in `HandlerBase` class is the opposite of DI because there is nothing injected but internally created. DI is not just using a DI Container but the ability to inject dependencies from outside via constructor, property or method. A DI Container is simply the sugar on the DI cake.

Comment: I miss a simple instruction like: Start the app, press Button A and that will happen, but I expected that something else should have happened. It is up to you to keep it as simple as possible for us to reproduce your issue. No one is going to invest a couple of minutes or hours only to get to your issue point. So please read very carefully what is meant to be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then rewrite your question to the minimum, reduce the project to a bare minimum and add the link to it the question.

Comment: The answer to the question about DI is simple, such a container is used by the organization in which it works as part of its technology stack. As for the other suggestions about containers, I understand, just thrown in the code is ctrl+c, ctrl+v from an existing project to prepare it faster. Now that you've brought up the DI topic, is there any reason why we should use an embedded container?

Comment: I edited the post to add steps for reproduction. I don't mean that i need a ready-made solution, rather suggestions on how I could implement such a "process view model" so that it uses reusable pages ( sending mostly as a result message). Maybe the very idea of this standalone view model does not make sense at all?